# Effective way to copy file in linux using C++?

Tags: c++

How to efficiently copy file in linux using C++?
Is there any syscalls/standard libraries that allow file copying without making loops?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy - It's crazy what a 5s google search can get you!

Comment: Please take some time to read the tour, and understand what the website is about before re-submitting your problem: http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: The best method is to use Linux API.  But, in order to copy a file, loops have to be performed, you can't get away without the loops.

Answer (score -1):

assuming argv[1] is the filename source and argv[2] is the filename dest:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int wid;
if(fork() == 0) {
    execve("/bin/cp", &argv[1], NULL);
    exit(-1);
}
wait(&wid);
```

What this does is fork the program and in the child execute the cp binary
For more information on the functions used:

```
man 2 fork
man 2 execve
man 2 wait
```

Comment: It's okay, now you know :) It's usually better to point them in the direction of the tour (http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Is the answered way  really better than using std::filesystem::copy ?